# Iphone base64 to video help or alterative solution(s)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, decoding

Info:

I need to create a completely standalone HTML page that includes javascript, images, and video. I have it all working for all browsers including mac OS except for iPhone. On iPhone, the video does not load properly. I am currently using Base64 encoding to have the video embedded into the HTML. I actually have the same video embedded twice one as a .webm and the other as a .mp4. Size and speed are not a priority (I know, weird)

This is how I have the video declared

```
<video id="objvideo">
<source type="video/webm" src="data:video/webm;base64,[data]">
<source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,[data]">
</video>
```

I have tried blob URL in addition to the base64 to possibly solve my problem but this failed you to yield any positive results. I am beginning to believe this is an encoding/decoding issue on safari mobile, although I'm not sure. (I'm not good at this whole development thing ;-;)

does anyone know of any possible solution they could me toward? or any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the src with javascript after page load possibly.

Answer (score 0):

the character " is missing on the end of source-tag

```
<source type="video/webm" src="data:video/webm;base64,[data]">
```